# Get child-pages slugs of current page into js-file

Tags: functions, javascript, slug

I'm querying all child pages on my current page with a custom Query like this.

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'page',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_parent'    => $post->ID,
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'orderby'        => 'menu_order'
    );
$subservice = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $subservice->have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php while ( $subservice->have_posts() ) : $subservice->the_post();?>
```

How do I get all slugs from these child pages into a javascript function?

I'm initialising my jQuery Plugin like this:

```
$('#pagepiling').pagepiling({
  sectionSelector: '.box',
  anchors: ['intro', 'section2','section3'],
  menu: '#menu'
)};
```

That means, the `anchors` option should display my child-page slugs from my current page.

Thanks for your help! Cara

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found what is arguably a cleaner way to do this...thanks to this other WPSE question [How do I add a php statement to a jQuery string](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/258423/how-do-i-add-a-php-statement-to-a-jquery-string).

I never new about [wp_localize_script()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/) until reading the answer to that question (I love WPSE :-).

## PHP

```
add_action ('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'localize_js') ;

function
localize_js ()
{
    global $post ;

    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'page',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_parent'    => $post->ID,
        'order'          => 'ASC',
        'orderby'        => 'menu_order'
        );
    $subservice = new WP_Query( $args );
    $slugs = array () ;

    while ( $subservice->have_posts() ) {
        $subservice->the_post();
        $slugs[] = $post->post_name ;
        }

    wp_reset_postdata () ;

    wp_enqueue_script ('my_script', plugins_url ('js/my_script.js', __FILE__), array (), false, true) ;
    // wp_localize_script() will handle the outputing of the relevant JS global decl
    wp_localize_script ('my_script', 'my_slugs', array ('slugs' => $slugs)) ;

    return ;
}
```

## JS, my_script.js

```
$('#pagepiling').pagepiling({
    sectionSelector: '.box',
    anchors: my_slugs.slugs,
    menu: '#menu'
)};
```

Answer (score 0):

When I need something like this I hook into [wp_print_styles](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_print_styles/) and output any values I need as JS globals, ala,

## PHP

```
add_action ('wp_print_styles', 'output_js') ;

function
output_js ()
{
    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'page',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_parent'    => $post->ID,
        'order'          => 'ASC',
        'orderby'        => 'menu_order'
        );
    $subservice = new WP_Query( $args );
    $slugs = array () ;
    global $post ;
    while ( $subservice->have_posts() ) {
        $subservice->the_post();
        $slugs[] = $post->post_name ;
        }

    $slugs = implode ("', '", $slugs) ;

    $js = <<<EOF
<style type='text/javascript'>
    var my_slugs = ['$slugs'] ;
</style>
EOF;

    echo $js ;

    wp_reset_postdata () ;

    return ;
}
```

## JS

```
$('#pagepiling').pagepiling({
    sectionSelector: '.box',
    anchors: my_slugs
    menu: '#menu'
)};
```

You could also do it via ajax, but that is more expensive.

Comment: When I use your code, my pagepiling js is breaking. I tried to get my_slugs via console.log in the javascript snippet in functions.php, but the variable is empty.

Comment: I just made 2 edits to my `output_js()` func: 1) added `global $post;` (lack of this is why it was failing) and 2) added `wp_reset_postdata();` (this makes sure that after `output_js()` the main loop will give the expected results.  It should work for you now.  Sorry for not actually testing my code locally before posting my answer.