# How do I add a php statement to a jQuery string

Tags: php, jquery, profiles, query-string

I want to insert a php statement into a jQuery String to update the user profile dynamically.

Here is my not working code so far:

```
jQueryVarWP("#kreis1").append("<option value=\""+array_list[i]+"\"<?php selected("+array_list[i]+", get_the_author_meta( \"kreis\", \$user->ID ) );?> >"+array_list[i]+"</option>");
```

My problem is somewhere here:

```
"<?php selected("+array_list[i]+", get_the_author_meta( \"kreis\", \$user->ID ) );?>
```

Maybe someone can help me to build this string.

Comment: Hi. You should have asked something like this on StackOverflow. This is completely out of scope here.

Comment: maybe for you, but this is still something i do in wordpress, so it is a wordpress issue ... in case you have nothing to say, just be quite =>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try to use wp_localize_script() to allow your javascript to use data that are normally only available using php. Here is the link in the codex that will help you do what you need:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script

Another way is to use a php to output your entire javascript code (in a php file, that is, and not a js file). That way you can use php the way you would normally do.

Comment: "Another way is to use a php to output your entire javascript code (in a php file, that is, and not a js file). That way you can use php the way you would normally do." --> any example here for me?

Comment: something like this:

    `<?php

    $foo = 'bar';

    echo '<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = " ' . $foo . ' ";</script>';

    ?>`

Comment: tried to echo the whole js without using the needed php, but now it says Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''); ' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\nuts\test.php on line 125

Comment: line 125 </script>';

Comment: Watch for characters that might need escaping.

Comment: worked, on line 110 was a '' that destroyed the logic behind, thank you very much so far :)

Comment: Cool! Glad to be of help.

Comment: okay and than just insert the function selected()?? problem here is it needs to look like selected($arg,get_the_author_meta("kreis1",$user->ID)) .... and $arg needs to be a js var array_list[i]

Comment: Just a tip, figure out where the php part goes, and where the javascript part goes, too.

`<?php echo '<script type="text/javascript"> var $arg = "something" '. selected( . ' $arg ' , get_the_author_meta("kreis1",$user->ID)) . '</script>'; ?>`

Comment: yeah that is clear, but the dynamic optionbox needs the value as a arg in selected to be saved -.- not as easy as i hoped, thank you a lot, i will now play search a way that combines everything :)

Comment: Please do not forget to upvote if you think this helped.

Comment: I did, but it says: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.